# scope of work or scope of works, which one is right and appropriate

Tags: grammar

Which one is the correct usage:

Scope of work to be completed

or

Scope of works to be completed.

Comment: It's very likely that you'll need *scope of work*. (Your username also suggests so.) In addition to "scope of work to be completed", you may want to consider "scope of work to be done", and "scope of work to be performed".

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about one work, then use the singular, "work". Like if you're describing the book or paper or research project that you are engaged in, that is one work, so you use the singular. If you were talking about many books, research projects, whatever, you might use "works". Like, "The scope of these works reaches from chemistry to history."